# Add id/name to array of objects in list

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a list `json_response` containing data (`text`, `created_at`, `id` etc.) on Twitter users following three different politicians. I want to add the name of the politician to each array so I know which users are connected to which politician.

The list `json_response`contain three objects. One object for each politician in the list `pol_names_list`. As I loop over `keyword` containing the search query is it possible to add the name of the specific politician in the `keyword` to the `json_response` if not can this step be added after extracting the data from the Twitter API?

```
pol_names_list = ['Doug Jones', 'Tim Kaine', 'Lindsey Graham'] # Names of politicians
```

```
json_response = []
for idx, i in enumerate(keyword):  # loop through list of politicians in keyword i.e. search query and extract tweets
    url = create_url(i, start_time, end_time, max_results)
    json_response.append(connect_to_endpoint(url[0], headers, url[1]))

    sleep(0.5)  # sleep for 0.5 seconds
    print(idx, i)
    pass

# keyword is printed when the loop has extracted tweets matching the keyword/query seen below
0 "blocked me" -vote -$2000 -Senate -House -is:retweet lang:en (DougJones OR "Doug Jones")
1 "blocked me" -vote -$2000 -Senate -House -is:retweet lang:en (timkaine OR "Tim Kaine")
2 "blocked me" -vote -$2000 -Senate -House -is:retweet lang:en (LindseyGrahamSC OR "Lindsey Graham")
```

The structure of `json_response` is printed below.

```
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))  # look at json_response object.
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "author_id": "17365499",
                "created_at": "2021-02-03T06:41:07.000Z",
                "id": "1356855217506066433",
                "text": "@walterbussart To think they could still have Doug Jones.  Ah well.   At least they spared the nation from the likes of Judge Roy Moore who is the only person who ever blocked me on Twitter (that I know of).  It is my one badge of honor."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1261060321306906625",
                "created_at": "2020-11-29T16:55:30.000Z",
                "id": "1333092232858116098",
                "text": "@RichardERock1 Doug Jones liked one of my tweets once\ud83d\ude0a\nOh, and Shatner blocked me"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "778040114056425473",
                "created_at": "2020-11-11T16:30:55.000Z",
                "id": "1326563065270312961",
                "text": "@CovfefeNDonuts @UnitedAsOne2020 @p0lyblank @DrJasonJohnson @DougJones @AOC And that\u2019s the most frustrating thing. We are on the same side. We want the same things. I had a prominent online  moderate tell me I was lying, said I was saying disingenuous bullshit, to get the hell out of his mentions, and blocked me... I spoke to him like I\u2019m speaking to you"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "3_1326274004064194560"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "1682312826",
                "created_at": "2020-11-10T21:22:19.000Z",
                "id": "1326274008157876225",
                "text": "@GUIGUI_gz @InfernalResistr @TheRealHoarse @meredithshiner @AOC @DougJones They blocked me \ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd23"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "15836506",
                "created_at": "2020-11-08T00:58:36.000Z",
                "id": "1325241276770488320",
                "text": "Tommy Tuberville blocked me a while back for some unknown reason, but I wonder what he thinks of this"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "3_1322357510121099264"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "1108587478414446592",
                "created_at": "2020-10-31T01:59:34.000Z",
                "id": "1322357513539366913",
                "text": "Ms. Roy Moore says to make sure you donate to Doug Jones if you can! \n\n(Somebody please tag ol\u2019 Roy. That beyotch blocked me.)"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "2749220978",
                "created_at": "2020-10-29T23:02:20.000Z",
                "id": "1321950523327680512",
                "text": "@HandsomeHawk250 @LeeAlle78291885 @DougJones Well he blocked me so \ud83e\udd37\ud83c\udffd\u200d\u2640\ufe0f"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "3_1309185055462432773"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "30402734",
                "created_at": "2020-09-24T17:36:56.000Z",
                "id": "1309185059979702272",
                "text": "@MatassaNagy @JCTheResistance @didikins4life @CaptMarkKelly @HickmanPolls @ossoff @ReverendWarnock @GreenfieldIowa @AmyMcGrathKY @SaraGideon @stevebullockmt @CalforNC @harrisonjaime @Bradshaw2020 @MBenDavid2020 @electpaulette @CJSenate2020 @PerkinsforLA @DougJones @SenGaryPeters @DrAlGrossAK So @CJSenate2020 blocked me for doing my civic duty of informing people of who he is. @NebraskaDems"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "167985567",
                "created_at": "2020-09-23T01:49:04.000Z",
                "id": "1308584132067373056",
                "text": "She blocked me. LOL"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "246124356",
                "created_at": "2020-09-07T00:49:55.000Z",
                "id": "1302771042155364355",
                "text": "@DougJones Well Dougie blocked me. He doesn't take kindly to the truth. #typicaldemocrat #WalkAway #Termlimits #Trump2020"
            }
        ],
        "includes": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media_key": "3_1326274004064194560",
                    "type": "photo",
                    "url": ""
                },
                {
                    "media_key": "3_1322357510121099264",
                    "type": "photo",
                    "url": ""
                },
                {
                    "media_key": "3_1309185055462432773",
                    "type": "photo",
                    "url": ""
                }
            ],
            "users": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2008-11-13T14:16:28.000Z",
                    "description": "Artist and Machinima director. #RESIST! MY THOUGHTS ARE FREE!",
                    "id": "17365499",
                    "name": "Larkworthy Antfarm",
                    "username": "Larkworthy"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-05-14T22:26:47.000Z",
                    "description": "Geek\ud83d\udd96, knitter\ud83e\uddf6, mother\ud83d\udc6a she/her",
                    "id": "1261060321306906625",
                    "name": "Karin Haasche",
                    "username": "hakelliese79"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2016-09-20T01:16:33.000Z",
                    "description": "Makeup Artist/Esthetician, Day Dreamer, Progressive, plotting my escape to a remote cabin in the woods on the daily.",
                    "id": "778040114056425473",
                    "name": "Alexandra Angelone",
                    "username": "AlexandraPaints"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2013-08-19T04:28:47.000Z",
                    "description": "Music / Writing / Awareness / Life / PlggdN / @NewFuryMedia",
                    "id": "1682312826",
                    "name": "beachdude",
                    "username": "beachdude42"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2008-08-13T13:29:12.000Z",
                    "description": "Attorney helping people at Husband of Fabulous Ashley. Father of 3.",
                    "id": "15836506",
                    "name": "Jon Lewis",
                    "username": "Jon_Lewis"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-03-21T04:33:46.000Z",
                    "description": "Am I beautiful? You butter believe I am. Am I better looking when caked in makeup? You\u2019re goddamn right. Am I a parody? Totally. \ud83d\ude09\ud83d\udc04 #DevinNunesPPPeedHisPants",
                    "id": "1108587478414446592",
                    "name": "DevinNunesTHEDragQueen",
                    "username": "NunesDrag"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-08-20T14:41:18.000Z",
                    "description": "\u262a\ufe0f| \ud83d\udd4c |\ud83d\udd4b|\ud83d\udcff| Small Business Owner|Immigrant Advocate|Proud Daughter of Immigrant Parents|Supporter of BLM and Chicano Movement|Horrible Story Teller|",
                    "id": "2749220978",
                    "name": "Luissa Sanchez",
                    "username": "Luissa_Sanchez"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-04-11T05:02:18.000Z",
                    "description": "mom ,Corp Travel Agent,love traveling,cooking & politics",
                    "id": "30402734",
                    "name": "Darlene",
                    "username": "travelchica67"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2010-07-18T02:27:28.000Z",
                    "description": "\ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\udf41#indigenousLivesMatter  \ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8 \ud83c\udf08\nI'm with @sindafukinrella, feck dem ugly step sistas.\n^^^ stepsistas is a metaphor for the wilfully stupid",
                    "id": "167985567",
                    "name": "\ud83c\udf80 \ud835\udc3b\ud835\udcb6\ud835\udcc7\ud835\udcc1\ud835\udc52\ud835\udcce\ud835\udc39\ud835\udcca\ud835\udcc0\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcc3\ud835\udc45\ud835\udc52\ud835\udcc1\ud835\udcc1\ud835\udcb6 \ud83c\udf80",
                    "username": "TheLadyHarley"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2011-02-02T05:12:42.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "246124356",
                    "name": "#MAGA",
                    "username": "9OneOnePatriot"
                }
            ]
        },
        "meta": {
            "newest_id": "1356855217506066433",
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fos5tfrf7zfagsgrg6qurkj9nii1dp",
            "oldest_id": "1302771042155364355",
            "result_count": 10
        }
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "author_id": "2877379617",
                "created_at": "2021-03-25T12:11:14.000Z",
                "id": "1375057688355336195",
                "text": "@prettynobodyco She blocked me in 2015 - for pointing out that Tim Kaine enables sexual assault in the military and the evidence was his killing of the MJIA and publicly stated that Military commanders should remain in charge of military rape cases. She's Tanden level awful. Congrats!"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1265018154444562440",
                "created_at": "2021-03-22T19:48:59.000Z",
                "id": "1374085719472361474",
                "text": "@MehcatCat @AlasscanIsBack @PattyArquette @timkaine Funny, they blocked me. \ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "2378324935",
                "created_at": "2021-03-07T21:32:13.000Z",
                "id": "1368675879312887810",
                "text": "@DrWinarick @KatieOGrady4 I apologize for any drama. Katie O Grady blocked me because we had a disagreement about Tim Kaine on one of your older posts. I guess I can't please everyone haha. :/"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "821870502943817729",
                "created_at": "2021-02-12T23:53:59.000Z",
                "id": "1360376637385244673",
                "text": "She blocked me a long ass time ago when I asked her why we shoulf care about Tim Kaine's personal view on abortion if it didn't impact legislation"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "16_1341045032732770306"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "17232340",
                "created_at": "2020-12-21T15:37:07.000Z",
                "id": "1341045038420275205",
                "text": "@DSingh4Biden @moomintroll8 @timkaine @GovernorVA That's why I replied to you. She blocked me previously, for what silliness I can't remember. Tough being a troll AND a snowflake"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "776959799871303681",
                "created_at": "2020-08-17T21:38:40.000Z",
                "id": "1295475153871212545",
                "text": "@Geechee4Kamala @WolvesforKamala She blocked me a while ago because I said Tim Kaine is a good man."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "526110389",
                "created_at": "2020-08-10T14:57:37.000Z",
                "id": "1292837513397035008",
                "text": "@SecularSpicoli @Embroiderista @RinzlerV1 @EricBoehlert @HillaryClinton @timkaine Spicoli blocked me \ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "3_1292139061143052289"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "1018552774844452864",
                "created_at": "2020-08-08T16:42:14.000Z",
                "id": "1292139064901206017",
                "text": "@2016GoPatriots @thunder0291 @brett5355 @CrepuscularFlow @HillaryClinton @timkaine He has now blocked me, lol"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "2819286966",
                "created_at": "2020-08-08T15:37:43.000Z",
                "id": "1292122828863660033",
                "text": "@jrwebber16 @HillaryClinton @timkaine Aww, she blocked me. \ud83d\ude02. Imagine being so disgusting that you support someone who is complicit in pedophilia, rape, and human trafficking. \ud83e\udd22\ud83e\udd2e"
            }
        ],
        "includes": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media_key": "16_1341045032732770306",
                    "type": "animated_gif"
                },
                {
                    "media_key": "3_1292139061143052289",
                    "type": "photo",
                    "url": ""
                }
            ],
            "users": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-11-15T02:23:57.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "2877379617",
                    "name": "Laura Saylor",
                    "username": "lauraleesaylor"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-05-25T20:33:36.000Z",
                    "description": "Weird Writer & Lunatic Linguist\nWicked Witch of the East\nshe/her",
                    "id": "1265018154444562440",
                    "name": "Zauberkind",
                    "username": "Zauberkind2"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-03-08T07:22:31.000Z",
                    "description": "#Resist, #BLM, #Vaxxed, liberal, autistic, kidney transplant survivor, political nerd, mental health advocate, fighter for equality, truth, justice, etc.",
                    "id": "2378324935",
                    "name": "Trevor \"Trev\" McKee Achilles",
                    "username": "MrTAchilles"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-01-19T00:02:52.000Z",
                    "description": "statist /  Progressive Gun Nut/ Single and hating it\n\n / \n\nstraight????? /\n\npronouns / brain worm survivor\n",
                    "id": "821870502943817729",
                    "name": "Puppet Enthusiast",
                    "username": "nihilisticpillo"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2008-11-07T15:09:46.000Z",
                    "description": "Liberal-Veteran-Dog Lover | Taste for irony, but in moderation | Humor is reason gone mad. ~Groucho Marx | I follow & unfollow back #VeteransResist #Resist",
                    "id": "17232340",
                    "name": "anti-Fascist Jim",
                    "username": "JimnBL"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2016-09-17T01:43:46.000Z",
                    "description": "MWF, I do not suffer fools. The South will not rise again.\n(she/her) #VoteLikeBlackWomen #StillWithHer\n#BidenHarris",
                    "id": "776959799871303681",
                    "name": "MarthaHC in Va",
                    "username": "wtf_imtooold"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2012-03-16T06:46:39.000Z",
                    "description": "SF girl living in AZ...it's a challenge! This killing them with kindness is taking way longer than I expected. #Resist #Vote",
                    "id": "526110389",
                    "name": "\u24df\u24d0\u24dc\u24d9\u24de\u24e8\u270c\ufe0f",
                    "username": "pamjoy67"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2018-07-15T17:48:00.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "1018552774844452864",
                    "name": "AladdinAne (OLED Model)",
                    "username": "AladdinAne"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-09-19T05:34:03.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "2819286966",
                    "name": "redacted",
                    "username": "redacted_1776"
                }
            ]
        },
        "meta": {
            "newest_id": "1375057688355336195",
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fo7md2mdwz40ydt36tiorz7xwyred9",
            "oldest_id": "1292122828863660033",
            "result_count": 9
        }
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "author_id": "737885223858384896",
                "created_at": "2021-03-26T21:56:02.000Z",
                "id": "1375567243082338314",
                "text": "@hogan_1969 @LindseyGrahamSC LOL She Blocked me.. could not admit the truth could she now. okay so where is her source for the shirts? and that is what he said. I (quote) We immediately surge the border all those seeking asylum. What about his lie about the cages? no Answer lol."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "847612931487416323",
                "created_at": "2021-03-26T21:55:24.000Z",
                "id": "1375567083791073283",
                "text": "@hogan_1969 @TeichTerry @thehill @LindseyGrahamSC @hogan_1969 just blocked me for showing her the actual numbers \ud83e\udd23\n\n#LiberalsHateFacts"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "18634205",
                "created_at": "2021-03-08T12:29:00.000Z",
                "id": "1368901564363051010",
                "text": "Huh.  Made me think if @LeaderMcConnell @LindseyGrahamSC @marcorubio @SenTedCruz feel trapped under the thumb of Trumpy.  And who else? @IvankaTrump? @MELANIATRUMP ? @DonaldJTrumpJr ? I\u2019d say Eric, but he blocked me."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "27327319",
                "created_at": "2021-03-02T11:53:16.000Z",
                "id": "1366718245521211393",
                "text": "@fedupinNHtoo @LindseyGrahamSC Exactly. I asked that question of a Republican on Facebook last night and she blocked me"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "917634626247647232",
                "created_at": "2021-02-28T18:16:45.000Z",
                "id": "1366089974907432961",
                "text": "@gop this is for you! @tedcruz @LindseyGrahamSC @MittRomney @mikepompeo\n#BitchyMcC blocked me!\ud83d\udc4d\nWatch \"Jack Off Jill - Hypocrite + lyrics\" on YouTube"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1231059979844456448",
                "created_at": "2021-02-26T04:25:49.000Z",
                "id": "1365156089554067459",
                "text": "@KelleyALynch1 @marwilliamson @therecount @LindseyGrahamSC She's fine with that just as she's fine with Biden's Nazis in Ukraine. She wants war with Russia, too. She blocked me for this tweet because she couldn't even condemn Biden's Nazis in Ukraine. She's a fauxgressive warmonger, a wolf in sheep's clothing."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1315477593303310336",
                "created_at": "2021-02-23T00:00:41.000Z",
                "id": "1364002202843451399",
                "text": "@MistyKitty3 @BlairMurray83 @FrankAmari2 @LindseyGrahamSC \ud83e\udd23 Someone didn\u2019t like what I said and blocked me."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1069115263671562240",
                "created_at": "2021-02-22T04:36:06.000Z",
                "id": "1363709124891070467",
                "text": "@trinkity88 @LindseyGrahamSC Apparently, @Trinkitty88 blocked me because FACTS are TOO HARD to handle!\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1303321972227690496",
                "created_at": "2021-02-20T19:38:49.000Z",
                "id": "1363211526316969985",
                "text": "@horsin64 @GovMurphy @LindseyGrahamSC You blocked me because you\u2019re a nifkin. It\u2019s not cyber tough you Nancy I\u2019d say it to your face. American lives matter before anyone else. America first and you don\u2019t like it because you have trump derangement. You\u2019re a psycho"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "27943005",
                "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:00:38.000Z",
                "id": "1362854626924650497",
                "text": "@TonyRom31334975 @staceyabrams @AnnaForFlorida @LindseyGrahamSC The guy blocked me on Twitter and had to unblock me after the Knight First Amendment Institute sued him and won&gt; I am certain It won't talk to me, but imagine..hehe?!"
            }
        ],
        "includes": {
            "users": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2016-06-01T05:55:21.000Z",
                    "description": "Biden Inflation the worst in 30 years. His Handlers trying to Rebrand Brandon is Hilarious.",
                    "id": "737885223858384896",
                    "name": "Biden is a complete mess and you know it.",
                    "username": "zelda3024"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-03-31T00:54:05.000Z",
                    "description": "Love God, Love Family, Love Country, Love Freedom - if we put those things first everything else will be great. MAGA",
                    "id": "847612931487416323",
                    "name": "Joey Bagadonuts",
                    "username": "AmericanGr8ness"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-01-05T15:25:55.000Z",
                    "description": "small & local garlic farmer; independent American; old surfer dude; working to find and speak truth to power; \ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8; mahalo and Maluhia",
                    "id": "18634205",
                    "name": "MacGregorGarlic",
                    "username": "MacGregorGarlic"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-03-28T22:53:28.000Z",
                    "description": "Let's Go Darwin!",
                    "id": "27327319",
                    "name": "Karen Kennedy",
                    "username": "KayKay68"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-10-10T06:15:18.000Z",
                    "description": "Mom\ud83d\udc95Cannactivist\ud83c\udf3fSecularHumanist\ud83c\udf10 BLM\u270a\ud83c\udfff\ud83c\udf08Ally\ud83e\udd8bCPTSD\u2695\ufe0f FTD\ud83e\udd14MeToo\ud83c\udf38ProChoice\ud83d\udc93CRPS\ud83d\ude23ClimateChange\ud83c\udf0e DACA\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf2AdoptDontShop\ud83d\udc3e#Steelers \ud83d\udda4\ud83d\udc9b #Vaxxed2TheMax\u270a\ud83d\udc9a",
                    "id": "917634626247647232",
                    "name": "Raven The Hemptress #LegalizeGlobally\ud83d\udc9a\ud83c\udf3f\u267f",
                    "username": "Kraven_Raven24"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-02-22T03:35:56.000Z",
                    "description": "Monetarism is the underlying cause of our disease; human progress and peace through development is the cure. Eurasian integration will benefit all of humanity!",
                    "id": "1231059979844456448",
                    "name": "\ud83c\udd70pocalypsis \ud83c\udd70pocalypseos \u2014 BRI Is The Future",
                    "username": "apocalypseos"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-10-12T02:21:21.000Z",
                    "description": "Father of two beautiful boys. Believer in the Constitution of the United States. Protector of my own rights. #Meatatarian",
                    "id": "1315477593303310336",
                    "name": "\ud83e\udd85 Steven Duggin \u2665\ufe0f \ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8\ud83d\uddfd",
                    "username": "itsStevenDuggin"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2018-12-02T06:25:16.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "1069115263671562240",
                    "name": "Barhag",
                    "username": "TheBarhag"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-09-08T13:19:17.000Z",
                    "description": "Not the liberals cup of tea",
                    "id": "1303321972227690496",
                    "name": "Christy",
                    "username": "Christy54177764"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-03-31T19:34:24.000Z",
                    "description": "NY-grown, FL-tanned, scribe, word nerd, TV junkie, game show champ, yenta, wife, twin mama, hot sauce collector, Bloody Mary maven &, says @NYPost, savvy gadfly",
                    "id": "27943005",
                    "name": "Lesley Abravanel",
                    "username": "lesleyabravanel"
                }
            ]
        },
        "meta": {
            "newest_id": "1375567243082338314",
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fosns35qj1snftmricbnwl7lr1frst",
            "oldest_id": "1362854626924650497",
            "result_count": 10
        }
    }
]
```

I imagine that the desired output could contain the name of the politician inside the `data` object with new value `pol_name` like so:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "pol_name": "Doug Jones",
                "author_id": "17365499",
                "created_at": "2021-02-03T06:41:07.000Z",
                "id": "1356855217506066433",
                "text": "@walterbussart To think they could still have Doug Jones.  Ah well.   At least they spared the nation from the likes of Judge Roy Moore who is the only person who ever blocked me on Twitter (that I know of).  It is my one badge of honor."
            },
...
...
...
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "pol_name": "Tim Kaine",
                "author_id": "2877379617",
                "created_at": "2021-03-25T12:11:14.000Z",
                "id": "1375057688355336195",
                "text": "@prettynobodyco She blocked me in 2015 - for pointing out that Tim Kaine enables sexual assault in the military and the evidence was his killing of the MJIA and publicly stated that Military commanders should remain in charge of military rape cases. She's Tanden level awful. Congrats!"
            },
...
...
...
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "pol_name": "Lindsey Graham",
                "author_id": "737885223858384896",
                "created_at": "2021-03-26T21:56:02.000Z",
                "id": "1375567243082338314",
                "text": "@hogan_1969 @LindseyGrahamSC LOL She Blocked me.. could not admit the truth could she now. okay so where is her source for the shirts? and that is what he said. I (quote) We immediately surge the border all those seeking asylum. What about his lie about the cages? no Answer lol."
            },
...
...
...
```

Comment: Your `json_response` looks like a regular Python object: a list of dicts with `data` pointing to a list of dicts. Navigate your way into your structure and set the value you want, it's fully writable when you're inside the program.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a list of interesting tokens from the names of your politicians. You likely want to do this more by hand to make sure you get all the interesting tokens. I'll do it like this for now, but this will not hit on "LindseyGrahamSC"

```py
pol_names_list = [
    'Doug Jones',
    'Tim Kaine',
    'Lindsey Graham'
]

pol_names_tokens = \
    set(p.lower() for p in pol_names_list) \
        .union(p.lower().replace(" ", "") for p in pol_names_list)
```

Let's also define a very simple tokenizer:

```py
import re
def simple_tokenize(text):
    return re.sub(r"\W", " ", text).split()
```

Now, given your data, lets run through the posts and see if we can find matches.

```py
matching_posts = []
for post in (post for row in response_data for post in row["data"]):
    matching_tokens = pol_names_tokens.intersection(simple_tokenize(post["text"].lower()))
    if matching_tokens:
        post["matching_tokens"] = list(matching_tokens)
        matching_posts.append(post)
```

Now we can print what we found:

```py
import json
print(json.dumps(matching_posts, indent=4))
```

giving us:

```
[
    {
        "author_id": "778040114056425473",
        "created_at": "2020-11-11T16:30:55.000Z",
        "id": "1326563065270312961",
        "text": "@CovfefeNDonuts @UnitedAsOne2020 @p0lyblank @DrJasonJohnson @DougJones @AOC And that\u2019s the most frustrating thing. We are on the same side. We want the same things. I had a prominent online  moderate tell me I was lying, said I was saying disingenuous bullshit, to get the hell out of his mentions, and blocked me... I spoke to him like I\u2019m speaking to you",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "dougjones"
        ]
    },
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_1326274004064194560"
            ]
        },
        "author_id": "1682312826",
        "created_at": "2020-11-10T21:22:19.000Z",
        "id": "1326274008157876225",
        "text": "@GUIGUI_gz @InfernalResistr @TheRealHoarse @meredithshiner @AOC @DougJones They blocked me \ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd23",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "dougjones"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author_id": "2749220978",
        "created_at": "2020-10-29T23:02:20.000Z",
        "id": "1321950523327680512",
        "text": "@HandsomeHawk250 @LeeAlle78291885 @DougJones Well he blocked me so \ud83e\udd37\ud83c\udffd\u200d\u2640\ufe0f",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "dougjones"
        ]
    },
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_1309185055462432773"
            ]
        },
        "author_id": "30402734",
        "created_at": "2020-09-24T17:36:56.000Z",
        "id": "1309185059979702272",
        "text": "@MatassaNagy @JCTheResistance @didikins4life @CaptMarkKelly @HickmanPolls @ossoff @ReverendWarnock @GreenfieldIowa @AmyMcGrathKY @SaraGideon @stevebullockmt @CalforNC @harrisonjaime @Bradshaw2020 @MBenDavid2020 @electpaulette @CJSenate2020 @PerkinsforLA @DougJones @SenGaryPeters @DrAlGrossAK So @CJSenate2020 blocked me for doing my civic duty of informing people of who he is. @NebraskaDems",     
        "matching_tokens": [
            "dougjones"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author_id": "246124356",
        "created_at": "2020-09-07T00:49:55.000Z",
        "id": "1302771042155364355",
        "text": "@DougJones Well Dougie blocked me. He doesn't take kindly to the truth. #typicaldemocrat #WalkAway #Termlimits #Trump2020",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "dougjones"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author_id": "1265018154444562440",
        "created_at": "2021-03-22T19:48:59.000Z",
        "id": "1374085719472361474",
        "text": "@MehcatCat @AlasscanIsBack @PattyArquette @timkaine Funny, they blocked me. \ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "timkaine"
        ]
    },
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "16_1341045032732770306"
            ]
        },
        "author_id": "17232340",
        "created_at": "2020-12-21T15:37:07.000Z",
        "id": "1341045038420275205",
        "text": "@DSingh4Biden @moomintroll8 @timkaine @GovernorVA That's why I replied to you. She blocked me previously, for what silliness I can't remember. Tough being a troll AND a snowflake",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "timkaine"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author_id": "526110389",
        "created_at": "2020-08-10T14:57:37.000Z",
        "id": "1292837513397035008",
        "text": "@SecularSpicoli @Embroiderista @RinzlerV1 @EricBoehlert @HillaryClinton @timkaine Spicoli blocked me \ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "timkaine"
        ]
    },
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_1292139061143052289"
            ]
        },
        "author_id": "1018552774844452864",
        "created_at": "2020-08-08T16:42:14.000Z",
        "id": "1292139064901206017",
        "text": "@2016GoPatriots @thunder0291 @brett5355 @CrepuscularFlow @HillaryClinton @timkaine He has now blocked me, lol",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "timkaine"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author_id": "2819286966",
        "created_at": "2020-08-08T15:37:43.000Z",
        "id": "1292122828863660033",
        "text": "@jrwebber16 @HillaryClinton @timkaine Aww, she blocked me. \ud83d\ude02. Imagine being so disgusting that you support someone who is complicit in pedophilia, rape, and human trafficking. \ud83e\udd22\ud83e\udd2e",
        "matching_tokens": [
            "timkaine"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi, @JonSG I appreciate your suggestion. However, I am not trying to insert the `user_id` and `user_name` into each object in the list. Instead, I wish to add the politician name/username that is named in the `text` from the list `pol_names_list`. I apologize if the title of the question is a bit confusing in relation to my actual question/issue.

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke Take a look and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JonSG. The code does come close to what I am trying to achieve. However, it does also remove the `includes` object containing `media` and `users` information that I need to process later on. For this reason, an optimal solution would be something similar to your code but without removing the `includes` object from `json_response`.